# Are templates one way of compile time polymorphism

Tags: c++, templates, compilation, polymorphism

Static binding is of two types

- Function Overloading
- Operator Overloading

Call to template functions is resolved at compile time, are they another way of implementing compile time polymorphism ?

Comment: Check out [CRTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp)

Comment: The answer is: Yes.